# What is Debian's default GPG keyserver, and where is it configured?

Tags: debian, gpg

I am playing with gpg verification on some kernel source, and trying to figure out where the gpg configuration file lives. Specifically, when I run `--receive-keys`, without providing keyserver, what does gpg do?

```
me@testing:~$ gpg2 -vv --receive-keys 647F28654894E3BD457199BE38DBBDC86092693E
gpg: data source: https://37.191.231.105:443
gpg: armor: BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK
```

however this 37.191.231.105 points to `analytics.sumptuouscapital.com`, and that puzzles me...

btw, I've tried `dpkg -L gnupg2` and no .conf file is installed, no .conf file in `~/.gnupg` folder either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The upstream default currently uses [the SKS keyservers](https://sks-keyservers.net/). The IP you saw is one of those listed for `hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net`:

```
$ dig +short hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net
209.244.105.201
37.191.231.105
192.146.137.98
```

This is set during compile time via [`configure.ac`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/gnupg2/blob/f9934dcb57ca482f399c0c744449d35f9e6b5792/configure.ac#L1873):

```
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED(DIRMNGR_DEFAULT_KEYSERVER,
                   "hkps://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net",
      [The default keyserver for dirmngr to use, if none is explicitly given])
```

That [will change soon](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/gnupg2/blob/93daa0064ee29372d93661cc6a9aa990f8c52414/debian/NEWS):

> gnupg2 (2.2.17-1) unstable; urgency=medium
>
> Upstream GnuPG now defaults to not accepting third-party
>   certifications   from the keyserver network.  Given that the SKS
>   keyserver network is   under attack via certificate flooding, and
>   third-party certifications   will not be accepted anyway, we now ship
>   with the more tightly-constrained   and abuse-resistant system
>   hkps://keys.openpgp.org as the default   keyserver.

Comment: thanks for the clear answer. A follow up question: I found the configure.ac file you mentioned in gpg source, and if I want to further confirm it is indeed compiled into the binary ELF: `strings \`which gpg2\` | grep hkps`, it returned none. Did I miss something?

Comment: As the line says, this is a setting for dirmngr, not gpg directly. Do you get the same result with dirmngr?

Comment: it is indeed embedded in dirmngr. thanks again.

Comment: This [change](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/gnupg2/-/commit/26c7b95d7) occurred in [Debian](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/gnupg2/-/commit/93daa0064) (only?).

Comment: The official repository [switched](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blobdiff;f=configure.ac;h=e651db8a0df4f8ad76f08a0df64d1e099ca77938;hp=0bdd90ed728aa56bbd31719141bfe555b90950fb;hb=47c4e3e00;hpb=5fe4b978875271fb55f1f674ab545bed2b97a7a8) to [keyserver.ubuntu.com](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blobdiff;f=NEWS;h=e37d5aa5d46276e0e3e462b7619c9678e374ab69;hp=c07308b3eb7ee5a2d02865b51e6579f553cea918;hb=695a879af;hpb=3283cf3a7a5e7f028cd7e622d53135a7091c08fc) only recently, and supposedly temporarily.